# Running code within XML documentation markup

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-web-api2, xml-documentation

This may be a stupid question, and I am betting the answer is no, but is there any way to have code run within the `/**` and `*/` tags used for documentation? In my case I have an API and want the `<returns>` tag to show a portion of the SQL query generated by the code, namely the columns selected from the DB. This is consistent in the application, this API always returns specific columns, but if we add more columns down the line, it'd be better if the programmer didn't have to update all routes that use this query string, just the string itself.

Right now I have the below for my returns tag:

```
/// <returns>LineItemID, InventoryCountID, ProductNumber, ProductName, ProductID, Vendor, VendorID, Location, LocationID, OnHand, Count, Variance, UnitCost</returns>
```

I want it to have.

```
//// <returns> InventoryCount.GetColumns() </returns>
```

InventoryCount.GetColumns() returns the list of columns as they appear in the tag I use now.

Comment: Can you show an example of how your `<returns>`-tag looks like?

Comment: @HimBromBeere added

Comment: So you want to execute the method in your docu-tag and instead of that method-call you want to print the results of this call into the tag? That would assume there are allready items when *compiling* your code which I´m pretty sure isn´t the case.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Like I said, I bet the answer is no, but I am hoping it's yes, and it doesn't hurt to ask. The static method uses a static variable which is a list of columns and aggregates them into a comma separated string.

Comment: You could produce the code, including the comments, from a T4 template, and do calls in that. It doesn't seem like a good idea though.

Comment: @JonHanna Apparently not - `Badly formed XML comment ignored for member`